# Mix in Faker methods - RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, faker

How could I access each Faker method under just one namespace:

```
any.sentence
any.name
... other methods from Faker::xxx classes
```

Instead of writing:

```
Faker::Lorem.sentence
Faker::Name.name
...
```

I am using RSpec and Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this, you could define your variable `any` which is equal to the namespaced class you want to call:

```
lorem = Faker::Lorem
lorem.sentence
#=> "Dignissimos eos qui doloribus quaerat sequi est corrupti error."

name = Faker::Name
name.name
#=> "Dr. Percival Ernser"
```

But please, consider this as a hack and not as something you should do in your code. Indeed, when someone will read you code (or you in a few months), seeing `Faker::Namespace` will appear as obvious. On the other hand reading `name.name` will lead to confusion for you will have to look for it's definition to understand what it does. Namespaces have a reason to exist and should not be overwritten to spare a few keystrokes.
Hope this answers you question!

EDIT: from you comment "unify all namespaces into one". This would not be possible (at least for `Faker`). Indeed, different methods have the same name, but in different namespaces. For instance, `Faker` has an implementation of the method `name` both in `Faker::Name` and `Faker::Company` (which yields different results).

As a consequence, unifying namespaces would not be possible since it would lead to loosing some methods.

Comment: I though having one namespace could not lead to confusion, since I could call that unified namespace `faker`. But your concern seems very valid. About the question, I was asking how to unify all namespaces into one something like this pseudo code: `Faker.classes.each do |c| c.methods.each do |m| faker.m = m end end`

Comment: Ah ok, instead of `Faker.classes` you should use `Faker.constants`. But there are two gotchas here: you will get things like `Config` or `Version`. But more important, how do you intend to differentiate `Faker::Company.name` from `Faker::Name.name` ?

Comment: hmm, it's more complicated, but it's possible. `faker.name` will yield a name, then when defining `name` the second time, it would be `faker.company_name`. Well I suppose it's too complicated, I am going to mark yours as the answer.